# Вычисление квартилей numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Сейчас начал учить статистику и дошел до квартилей. И столкнулся с проблемой, что numpy вычисляет квартили как-то странно. Насколько я понял, чтобы найти нижний квартиль, нужно взять часть данных до медианы и найти медиану там. Вот пример:

```
arr = np.arange(1, 11)
print(f'{np.quantile(arr, 0.25)} - 1st Qu.')
print(f'{np.quantile(arr, 0.5)} - median')
print(f'{np.quantile(arr, 0.75)} - 3st Qu.')

3.25 - 1st Qu.
5.5 - median
7.75 - 3st Qu.
```

Так как число элементов четно, то медиана здесь 5.5, тут все понятно. Но вот что с первым квантилем? Мы получаем часть 1, 2, 3, 4 - здесь медиана 2.5, те не сходится. Я подумал что надо брать еще часть значений: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - тут медиана 3. Аналогично с 3 квартилем. Я гуглил, но везде написано, что считаю я все верно. Я проверял на цифрах, которые были в уроке и там все хорошо:

```
np.array([157,159,161,164,165,166,167,167,167,168,169,169,170,170,170,171,171,172,172,172,172,173,173,175,175,177,178,178,179,185])

# Первый квартиль
print(np.quantile(hights, 0.25))
# Второй квартиль
print(np.quantile(hights, 0.50))
# Третий квартиль
print(np.quantile(hights, 0.75))
# Четвертый квартиль
print(np.quantile(hights, 1))

167.0
  170.5
  173.0
  185
```

В коментах к уроку люди тоже не понимают, почему иногда не работает вычисление, точнее работает, но не как объясняли. Знатоки - помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: 3.25 - правильно. Что не так?

Comment: А доку читали? Там туча методов, как их можно считать. Медиана - это только один из. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html

Comment: @MBo, Как вы это посчитали?

Comment: @CrazyElf читал, чтобы вычислить первый квартиль нужно указать в методе 0.25

Comment: @Андрей Это понятно. Но там написано, что есть туча методик, как этот самый квартиль 0.25 можно посчитать. Кроме медианы там ещё туча вариантов есть самых разных. И все они могут давать разный результат.

Comment: @CrazyElf капец, темный лес какой-то

Comment: @Андрей Да, статистика как наука - это капец, всё верно ))  Базовые то понятия простые, а как чуть глубже копать начинаешь, там уже не тривиальная математика и заумные термины.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По применённому методу:

Имеем диапазон **индексов** `0..n-1`

При нечётном `n` медиана располагается на индексе `(n-1)/2`, при чётном - посередине между индексами `(n-2)/2` и `n/2`, её значение - полусумма `(a[(n-2)/2] + a[n/2]) / 2`. Это, как я понимаю, уже ясно.

Теперь квантиль `q` - он должен находиться на индексе `quantile(q) = q*(n-1) = g = i + f`, где `i` - целая часть числа `g`, `f` - дробная часть этого числа.  Значение квантиля при линейном методе (по умолчанию) равно `a[i]*(1-f) + a[i+1]*f`

Можно проверить для первого примера.

```
n = 10
n-1 = 9
q=0.25 =>  
g = 9*0.25 = 2.25 = 2 + 0.25
                    ^     ^
                    i     f 

a[i] * (1- f) + a[i+1] * f = 
 3   *  0.75  +   4    * 0.25 = 3.25
```

Comment: А почему мы именно 9 берем, я не особо понял какого именно числа целая часть

Comment: n - длина массива, индексы от 0 до n-1, для range 1..11 длина n=10, последний индекс 9

Comment: а f дробная часть чего? Квартиля, как я понял, судя по 0.25

Comment: числа q*(n-1), где q - значение квантиля (1/4 для первого квартиля)